# jQuery Toggle (IE 7)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, slidetoggle

Why wont this work in IE 7?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://www.k-e-w-l.ca/slideToggle.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played around for a little bit and it seems you want to enable the click action on the link that is being clicked, rather than the `li` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle_container").hide();

    $("li.trigger a").click(function() {
        $(".toggle_container").hide();
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    });

});
```

`$` is just an alias for `jQuery`

There's also a problem with your HTML, in that you have divs as children of your `ul` element. You can just have another `ul` within the list item itself. As another point, an ID should be unique for each DOM element.

I've put this up as a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8q8jy/1/

Comment: Ah - my bad. I didn't notice the errors in your HTML. I've updated my answer (and the jsFiddle) and it works in GC,FF and IE for me.

Comment: i was focussing so much on the jquery i didnt realize the simple html error.  This is perfect. Thanks a lot!